# Why findById response is id not found but findAll returns object with this id

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I can't find the mistake in my code. Looking for help. Why does the method `findById()` return no such object with this id but `findAll()` displays this object with this id?

This is my `class User`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "user")
    private UserDetails userDetails;
}
```

My `class UserDetails`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "userdetails")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

My controller:

```java
@RestController
public class AnotherUserController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AnotherUserController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/demo/{id}")
    public User findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("user not found: " + id));
    }

    @PostMapping("/demo")
    public User save(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @GetMapping("/demo")
    public Iterable<User> save() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

My repository:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

And logs:

```
2020-07-05 22:11:30.642 ERROR 13200 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception 
[Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: user not found: 23] with root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: user not found: 23
...
..
.
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using spring? Tag your post properly.

Comment: Probably because of `@OneToOne`, do you have matching `UserDetails` in the database?

Comment: enable sql logging will help

Comment: Does this user have related `UserDetails`?

Comment: Incidentally, the Column name only needs to be specified if your property and database name do not follow Spring Boot's naming conventions (Java "myDatabaseField" -> SQL "MY_DATABASE_FIELD"), so you can drop that on your id, login and password fields.

Comment: @Taschi agree but doesn't help.

Comment: @Shadov Yes something wrong with `@OneToOne` because without this field `findById()` returns `User` as expected.

Comment: That's why You should always enable sql logging during development. You would find the cause directly. Don't never be blinded of what your orm generates as SQL statement.

Comment: Can someone helps with resolving this?    
```Hibernate:    
select    
 user0_.id as id1_1_0_,    
 user0_.login as login2_1_0_,    
 user0_.password as password3_1_0_,    
 userdetail1_.id as id1_0_1_,    
  userdetail1_.name as name2_0_1_,    
  userdetail1_.surname as surname3_0_1_,    
  userdetail1_.user_id as user_id4_0_1_    
   
from users user0_    
inner join userdetails userdetail1_    
on user0_.id=userdetail1_.user_id    
where user0_.id=?```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so you have `@OneToOne(optional = false)` relation, and as you said in the comments, this field is a problem. Finding by id does not return users, because hibernate does `inner join` to `userdetails`, and since there is no matching record - there is no result.

So the fix is simple: if you want your users returned even when they have no relation to details - mark the relation as optional - `@OneToOne(optional = true)`. Hibernate will then generate `left outer join` instead of `inner join`.

If the relation is not optional (from business point of view), then you should not allow such situation to happen that there exists a user without details. Making that check on a database level would be the best (non-null foreign keys etc.).

btw `findAll` returns results, because it translates to `select * from users` (no joins) and then fetches details lazily if needed